# HX711 loadcell amplifier with builtin mcu communication problem

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, i2c, serial, communication

I bought the following version of HX711 module.

[image: BOB Front]

[image: BOB Back]

Connection to Arduino
VCC -> 5V
GND -> GND
SCK/TX -> GPIO 6
DT/RX -> GPIO 7

However, it doesn't work. I have tried different libraries and even different boards but there seems to be communication problem with the module.
I assume it has something to do with the mcu chip and the jumper connections J3 & j4. The mcu chip is STC 8F1k08.

There are a lot of tutorials regarding HX711 modules but I couldn't find any info about this particular board with an MCU. There is some info (chinese translation) on the sellers page but doesn't say anything about the jumper config. [Product page](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32860114708.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.3c30769fppQAfk&algo_pvid=799db5cc-75b8-4ac2-9cb8-8c37499b85db&algo_exp_id=799db5cc-75b8-4ac2-9cb8-8c37499b85db-1&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000024686706526%22%7D)

I tried to find any relevant info in the [MCU datasheet](http://www.stcmicro.com/stc/stc8f1k08s2.html) but with my limited knowledge of MCUs it didn't help much. Apparently it's possible to communicate  through Serial & I2C with this MCU.

From the datasheet [image: MCU pinout]
it looks like, J3 connects SCL & Tx, while J4 connects SDA with common ground. I am confused as it seems like mixing I2C with UART.

So can someone please help me solve the communication issue?

Comment: The web site documentation says the MCU makes it serial only (default 9600 baud), so any I2C library you use will fail.

Comment: I have used this "old" HX711 to uV levels range (with digital average ) ... I don't know this "version", but it seems that you can (if any problem) however remove MCU easily ...

Comment: @JackCreasey Most of the libraries I tried, used Serial comm. e.g.  this one https://github.com/bogde/HX711 but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The library you point to is a Synchronous serial driver for the HX711 chip. The board you have wants to send Asynchronous Serial @9600 baud.

Comment: I searched for HX711 asynchronous driver but didn't find a library. So if I understand correctly the HX711 communicates via synchronous serial but the MCU chip communicates using the asynchronous serial. Guess I need to write my library to be able to communicate with this module :(

Answer (score 0):

same problem,solder jumpers j3 and j4,remove soip8 mcu and work ok....

Comment: user365057 - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. Can you add more details? What exactly happens when you solder across J3 & J4? Are you saying that you had to desolder the MCU or something else? etc. || If you can add more details, please [edit] the answer. || As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] to see how Stack Exchange differs from typical forums.

Answer (score 0):

The other [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/702629/101063) said just:

> same problem,solder jumpers j3 and j4,remove soip8 mcu and work ok....

Based upon the information in the question and looking at the traces visible on the HX711 module a partial schematic is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnsVLY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where:

- The [HX711](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf) is a *24-Bit Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC) for Weigh Scales* which has a SPI like interface using the `PD_SCLK` and `DOUT` pins.
- The STC [8F1K08](https://www.stcmicro.com/datasheet/stc8a-8f-en.pdf) is an 8-pin MCU with a 8051 core, with presumably contains a UART to SPI based conversion between the `TX` and `RX` pins on the `J2` connector of the module and the HX711 load cell ADC.

So, the referenced answer shows that by removing the pre-programmed MCU `U2` and fitting jumpers for `J3` and `J4`, that changes the `J2` connector pins to `SCK` and `DT` to give a SPI interface to the HX711 load cell ADC.